# In Start Method I use Aggregated Query (queries use GROUP By ),then how to check In Execute Method Limit&Number of records we can get using this Query

Tags: apex, batch, aggregate, iterable

In Start Method I use Aggregated Query (queries use GROUP By ),then how to check In Execute Method the Aggregate Query how much record Fetch Limit & Number of records we can get using Aggregate Query

here I'm trying like

```
    global class AggregateQueryBatch implements Database.Batchable<AggregateResult> {
    
    global Iterable<AggregateResult> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        String query = 'SELECT COUNT(Id), Account__c FROM account_allowances__c GROUP BY Account__c';
        return new AggregateResultIterable(query);
    }    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){ 
        for(sObject sObj : scope) {
          AggregateResult ar = (AggregateResult)sObj;
          System.debug('>>>> COUNT : ' + ar.get('cnt'));
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    }
}
```

and get error like "**Invalid type: AggregateResultIterable**"
please give me the best suggestion to find the limit and number of record fetch by using of Aggregate Query.
Here "account_allowances__c" have more then 50,000 record
Thanks

Comment: Just a general note that in programming, you can't just type whatever you want. You need to use classes/methods/variables that the language provides to you (things like `List<AggregateResult>`, `Opportunity`, `JSON.deserialize()`) or define them yourself if they don't exist. `AggregateResultIterable` isn't provided by Apex, and you haven't made an Apex class for that, so you, unsurprisingly, get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do an inline query:

```
public Iterable<AggregateResult> start(Database.BatchableContext context){
    return [SELECT COUNT(Id), Account__c FROM account_allowances__c GROUP BY Account__c];
}
```

Note that you'll be limited to **2,000 accounts** in this case, otherwise you'll get an exception, because `AggregateResult` queries do not generate database cursors.

It would be better to start from accounts and work backwards:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
      SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Account_Allowances__c)
    ]);
}
```

This query will work for up to 50,000,000 records. In your `execute` method, you can then figure out how many account allowances there are for the selected accounts:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
  Account_Allowances__c[] allowances = [
    SELECT Account__c 
    FROM Account_Allowances__c 
    WHERE Account__c = :scope
  ];
  // rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response
My question is When I use Aggregate query in batch class, How many record we can Fetch?

Comment: @sunnyroxx 2,000 aggregate rows.